# bash parameter variables in script problem

Tags: bash, variables

I have a script I wrote for switching to root or running a command as root without a password. I edited my /etc/sudoers file so that my user [matt] has permission to run /bin/su with no password. This is my script "s" contents:

```
matt: ~ $ cat ~/bin/s
#!/bin/bash

[ "$1" != "" ] && c='-c'

sudo su $c "$*"
```

If there are no parameters [simply `s`], it basically calls `sudo su` which goes to root with no password. But if I put paramaters, the $c variable equals "-c", which makes su execute a single command.

It works good, except for when I need to use spaces. For example:

```
matt: ~ $ touch file\ with\ spaces
matt: ~ $ s chown matt file\ with\ spaces 
chown: cannot access 'file': No such file or directory
chown: cannot access 'with': No such file or directory
chown: cannot access 'spaces': No such file or directory
matt: ~ $ s chown matt 'file with spaces'
chown: cannot access 'file': No such file or directory
chown: cannot access 'with': No such file or directory
chown: cannot access 'spaces': No such file or directory
matt: ~ $ s chown matt 'file\ with\ spaces'
matt: ~ $
```

How can I fix this?

Also, what's the difference between **$*** and **$@** ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ah, fun with quoting.  Usually, the approach @John suggests will work for this: use `"$@"`, and it won't try to interpret (and get confused by) the spaces and other funny characters in your parameters.  In this case, however, that won't work because su's -c option expects the entire command to be passed as a single parameter, and then it'll start a new shell which parses the command (including getting confused by spaces and such).  In order to avoid this, you actually need to re-quote the parameters within the string you're going to pass to `su -c`.  bash's `printf` builtin can do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
    sudo su -c "$(printf "%q " "$@")"
else
    sudo su
fi
```

Let me go over what's happening here:

1. You run a command like `s chown matt file\ with\ spaces`
2. bash parses this into a list of words: "s" "chown" "matt" "file with spaces".  Note that at this point the escapes you typed have been removed (although they had their intended effect: making bash treat those spaces as part of a parameter, rather than separators between parameters).
3. When bash parses the `printf "%q " "$@"` command in the script, it replaces `"$@"` with the arguments to the script, with parameter breaks intact.  It's equivalent to `printf "%q " "chown" "matt" "file with spaces"`.
4. `printf` interprets the format string "%q " to mean "print each remaining parameter in quoted form, with a space after it".  It prints: "chown matt file\ with\ spaces ", essentially reconstructing the original command line (it has an extra space on the end, but this turns out not to be a problem).
5. This is then passed to sudo as a parameter (since there are double-quotes around the `$()` construct, it'll be treated as a single parameter to sudo).  This is equivalent to running `sudo su -c "chown matt file\ with\ spaces "`.
6. `sudo` runs `su`, and passes along the rest of the parameter list it got including the fully escaped command.
7. `su` runs a shell, and it also passes along the rest of its parameter list.
8. The shell executes the command it got as an argument to `-c`: `chown matt file\ with\ spaces`.  In the normal course of parsing it, it'll interpret the unescaped spaces as separators between parameters, and the escaped spaces as part of a parameter, and it'll ignore the extra space at the end.
9. The shell runs `chown`, with the parameters "matt" and "file with spaces".  This does what you expected.

Isn't bash parsing a hoot?

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly. However, I just made a script to experiment `printf`
here is my script:

`#!/bin/bash
printf "%q" "$@";`

when I call it like this [the name is "i"];
`$ i a b c d e f g`
the output is
`abcdefg`
why is it all squished up? and if it's squished up, then why does it work in my script `s`? lol

Comment: @Matt: printf doesn't add spaces, so in order to get them you have to include a space after `%q` (`"%q "` instead of just `"%q"`).  This also adds a space after the last parameter; if that were a problem (it isn't here), you'd have to do something more complicated, like `printf "%q" "$1"; printf " %q" "${@:2}"` (i.e. print the first argument with no space, then the rest of the arg list each preceded by a space).

Comment: Ohh!! Ok. So anyway I just realized... If I run `s` w/o any args, it says `Unknown id: ''`... run like `bash -x s` it outputs `matt: ~ $ bash -x s
+ '[' '' '!=' '' ']'
++ printf '%q '
+ sudo su ''\'''\'' '
Unknown id: ''`
so what I did was change the script, if $1 is empty then run `sudo su&&exit` so it exits before the printf [which obviously is writing quotes and messing up the "sudo su" command while run without args]

Comment: @Matt: You're right, it didn't handle being run with no arguments properly.  I've edited it to (hopefully) fix the problem.

Comment: Nice, ok, I will use that rather than what I had, because it looks neater this way =)

Comment: Just a note for anyone who stumbles over this, note that (as in the posted answer) you must have `#!/bin/bash` or, say, `#!/bin/zsh` as the first line; it doesn't work if it's just `#!/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 3):

`"$*"` collects all the positional parameters (`$1`, `$2`, …) into a single word, separated by one space (more generally, the first character of `$IFS`). Note that in shell terminology, a word can include any character including spaces: `"foo bar"` or `foo\ bar` parses to a single word. For example, if there are three arguments, then `"$*"` is equivalent to `"$1 $2 $3"`. If there is no argument, then `"$*"`  is equivalent to `""` (an empty word).

`"$@"` is a special syntax that expands to the list of positional parameters, each in its own word. For example, if there are three arguments, then `"$@"` is equivalent to `"$1" "$2" "$3"`. If there is no argument, then `"$@"` is equivalent to *nothing* (an empty list, not a list with one word that is empty).

`"$@"` is almost always what you want to use, as opposed to `"$*"`, or unquoted `$*` or `$@` (the last two are exactly equivalent and perform filename generation (a.k.a. globbing) and word splitting on all the positional parameters).

There's an additional problem, which is that `su` except a single shell command as the argument of `-c`, and you're passing it multiple words. You've had [a detailed explanation of getting the quoting right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809783/bash-parameter-variables-in-script-problem/5812109#5812109), but let me add advice on how to do it right, which sidesteps the double quoting issues. You may also want to refer to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3063/how-do-i-run-a-command-as-the-system-administrator-root for more background on `sudo` and `su`.

`sudo` already runs a command as root, so there's no need to invoke `su`. In case your script has no argument , you can just run a shell directly; unless your version of `sudo` is very old, there's an option for that: `sudo -s`. So your script can be:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then set -- -s; else set -- -- "$@"; fi
exec sudo "$@"
```

(The else part is to handle the rare case of a command that begins with `-`.)

I wouldn't bother with such a short script though. Running a command as root is unusual and risky enough that typing the three extra characters shouldn't be a problem. Running a shell as root is even more unusual and risky and surely deserves six more characters.

Comment: Actually there is a need to invoke `su`... If you read my question carefully, you notice, the purpose of my script is to run root commands as root without a password! So I need sudo to call su as root. [without a password] Actually, now that I think of it, I could also allow /usr/bin/sudo to be run without a password [in /etc/sudoers].

Comment: @Matt: Granting permission to run `su` has the same effect in terms of security as granting permission to run any command. But it's more complex; for example you run into extra quoting issues that led you to ask this question. In security, complexity is very much a bad thing. So, *for security reasons*, remove this rule granting you the permission to run `su` and replace it by the permission to run any command.

Comment: Security? I thought Linux was already secure. Nobody else has access to my computer anyway [besides my fam], and they don't even know how to use the Terminal. xD
And I am not sure I understand. Do you mean, instead of writing `NOPASSWD:/bin/su` I should use `NOPASSWD:/bin/mount,/bin/umount,/every/other/command` ?? that's ridiculous

Comment: Oh and what I forgot to say in my first comment, running commands as root is **not** unusual. it is actually very common, cuz I am my own sysadmin ;)

Comment: @Matt: Instead of `/bin/su`, use `ALL`. This will have exactly the same impact in terms of security (i.e. you can do everything), without the extra complications.

Comment: well I do use "ALL". this is my line in /etc/sudoers: `matt    ALL =  NOPASSWD:/bin/su`

Comment: @Matt: `ALL` as the *command*, not as the host specification. `matt ALL = NOPASSWD: ALL` (as in the example in the `sudoers` manual).